# Adding a Toolbar button programatically in Lotus Notes client R7?

Tags: lotus-notes

Is there a way to programmatically add a Toolbar button in the Lotus Notes 7 client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the application found on the link below or you can inspect the code to make your own utility.

http://www.eview.com/eview/VOLR6.nsf/0/00BAF435E672A4FE8525710D0077296F/$File/Toolbar%20Library.nsf

Hope this helps.